# Ubuntu won't load after switching from X11 to Wayland

Tags: boot, xorg, wayland

Was switching from x11 to Wayland
Wayland, following this [guide](https://helpdesk.psionline.com/hc/en-gb/articles/13470827149332-How-to-perform-the-switch-from-the-Wayland-display-server-to-Xorg-X11-on-Linux-Ubuntu-22-04-LTS) - the 2nd method

After I modified the file content of
`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

I restarted using
`sudo systemctl restart gdm3`

in the terminal.

It shuts off, and when booted, it's stuck on a blue screen. It boots into bios (I see the Ubuntu and Lenovo logos), but it won't load into Ubuntu.

Before going right into the blue screen, it gives me this:
[image: pic of text before blue screen]

`Bluetooth: hcio: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02`

Although I don't think it's related

Restart didn't work :(
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You've not provided your Ubuntu product & release details; (ie. are you using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop? Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop? etc).  What actual change(s) did you make?? (*no changes are required to configs to achieve what you wanted; you can logout of a Wayland session & start an Xorg session by selecting it at login; a link to what you intended to follow is only helpful if you're specific as to what you actually did including any typos etc made*)

Comment: Updated. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Apologies. Also, I tried the login screen method, but apparently a bug causes the gear icon to not show on the screen, so i couldn't find it

Comment: You did not add how you modified the contents of custom.conf. The error may be in your edit. With this, nobody can help you if you do not disclose what was changed. In addition, mention your graphics card.